# Google script to copy and paste

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to work out if it's possible to write a script that will copy and paste special all the values in a tab with the same name across multiple workbooks in a file?
This is what I have so far but I just can't seem to get it to work properly? Any help would be most appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Copy and Paste')
      .addItem('Copy and paste sheet with new name', 'copyAndPasteSheetWithNewName')
      .addToUi();
}

function copyAndPasteSheetWithNewName() {
  var sheetName = Browser.inputBox('Enter the name of the sheet to copy and paste:');
  var folder = DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId()).getParents().next();
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var workbook = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    var sheet = workbook.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  }
}
}
```

Comment: Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue from `but I just can't seem to get it to work properly`, in your showing script, it seems that `spreadsheet` of `spreadsheet.getActiveRange()` is not declared. Is this related to your current issue?

Comment: Sorry Tanaike, I didn't really explain myself very well. When I run it I get an error message saying 'Spreadsheet not defined' which is what I'm assuming you noticed. I'm a complete novice at this and have patched together code from the internet to get this far. If I just want to paste special the data where it is how do I define that in the code?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `If I just want to paste special the data where it is how do I define that in the code?`, I cannot understand your expected result. Can I ask you the detail of your actual question? By this, I would like to try to understand it.

Comment: No worries Tanaike, I'm sorry that I'm not very good at explaining what i need here. What I'm trying to do is just have the final part of the script hard code the worksheet. It's full of formulas and I want the results of those formulas not the formulas themselves.

Comment: During the week the sheet updates and then on Monday morning I create a new one and need the old one to stop updating. I hope that makes more sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your reply and your expected result, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From your following reply,

> What I'm trying to do is just have the final part of the script hard code the worksheet. It's full of formulas and I want the results of those formulas not the formulas themselves.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns()).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); //  or range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly: true});
```

- By this modification, the last row of each sheet is converted to only the values without the formulas.

Comment: Tanaike, you are an absolute legend. Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it., it works like a dream.

Comment: @Jezzer About `it works like a dream.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer